# Defining Function Arguments and List Iteration

Tags: python, function, arguments, iteration

I am EXTREMELY new to Python but have experience in javascript. Below is a portion of my program that is not running as the argument "data" in "remove_comment_lines" is not defined. How can I define data and use it as an argument for the specified function WITHOUT using "global" as it is not permitted by my professor.

## Reads file and returns a list of lines in string format

```
def read_data(data):
    with open("in.dat", "r") as f:
        data = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    return data

read_data("in.dat")


# Takes a list of lines as input and returns a new list of lines with the 
# comment lines (the ones that begin with #) removed.
def remove_comment_lines(data):
    with open("in.dat", "w") as f1:
        for number, data in enumerate(data):
            if number not in [0,1,2]:
                f1.write(data)
    f1.close()

remove_comment_lines(data)
```

HERE IS THE FILE "in.dat"

```
# read from file data about one day 
# format: start_time:end_time:#steps
09.30AM:09.45AM:220
11.45AM:12.23PM:300
11.45AM:10.23AM:302
2.45PM:3.23PM:202
3.45PM:3.53PM:90
5.45PM:5.53PM:80
6.45PM:7.23PM:1000
10.45PM:10.53PM:102
```

I have tried absolutely everything I can think of. I am expecting the functions to open file "indat" and remove the lines that begin with a "#" and return a list separated by lines.

Comment: `data` as input of `read_data` is no needed. you could just do `read_data()` then when you call this function you need to assign output of this function to a variable let say: `data = read_data()`  hope it helps.  if you have more doubts let me know

Comment: Why do you remove the 1st **three** lines, while only the 1st 2 are comments; and more generally, this assumes the comments are always on specific lines; change your logic to write the line to the file `if not line.startswith('#'):` . Furthermore, your 2nd function doesn't **return** anything, it writes the filtered lines to a file.

Answer (score 0):

`with` context manager doesn't require you to use `f.close()`.
you can use `if line.startswith('#'): continue` to just move to the next iteration of the loop/file rather that write the line.
https://onlinegdb.com/Fr3wQYvoD

```py
def read_data(data):
    with open("in.dat", "r") as f:
        data = f.readlines()
    return data

# Takes a list of lines as input and returns a new list of lines with the 
# comment lines (the ones that begin with #) removed.
def remove_comment_lines(data):
    with open("in.dat", "w") as f:
        for line in data:
            if line.startswith('#'): continue
            f.write(line)

# read file as list of lines and save to variable
data = read_data("in.dat")

# pass data to remove comment function
remove_comment_lines(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the function to **return** a list of lines, as mentioned, instead of **cleaning** the file, here's a working function:

```
def read_data_and_filter_out_comments(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        return [line for line in f.readlines() if not line.startswith('#')]

out_data = read_data_and_filter_out_comments('in.dat')

# ['09.30AM:09.45AM:220\n', '11.45AM:12.23PM:300\n', '11.45AM:10.23AM:302\n', '2.45PM:3.23PM:202\n', '3.45PM:3.53PM:90\n', '5.45PM:5.53PM:80\n', '6.45PM:7.23PM:1000\n', '10.45PM:10.53PM:102']
```